# Angular 6 Image issue on build

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am having an issue while calling background image using scss.
If i use **src: url(/assets/fonts/Montserrat/Montserrat-Bold.ttf);**, it works in my serve command but not in by build command.

And if I remove / form the url its not working in the serve command as well.

Kindly help as I have tried every possible solution.

Comment: You can update base href tag in your html to locate the exact path of assets or any other resource.

Comment: i am calling a background image and not an image in html

Comment: so if your production deploy is a static server url link like hostname.com/myangularapp/ the browser will try to get the assets from hostename.com/assets instead of hostname.com/myangularapp/assets

Comment: what url do you serve the app from after you build it?

Comment: hi @AvinKavish, i am deploying my app in sub directory and not in the root folder.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-base-tag

Comment: hi @Vash72, yes thats the exact issue and if I remove the / from the path once i deployed it on the the server, then the images load properly